# PhpStormのAdd Composer Dependencyでエラーになってしまう

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel, composer

mac上でPhpStormを使ってLaravel5の開発を行っております。

PhpStormからComposerを使ってみようと思い、メニューから以下の操作をしたのですが、エラーとなってしまいました。何か解決方法はあるでしょうか？
ちなみに、ターミナル端末から、composerを使った場合は特に問題はありません。

メニュー操作： Tools > Composer > Add Dependency...

Add Composer Dependency画面
[image: Add Composer Dependency画面とエラー内容]
エラー内容

> Could not get package info. Failed to connect to https://packagist.org/packages/list.json: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair Please check your internet connection.

Googleで検索したところ、JDK1.8 をインストールすると直るとの情報を得たのですが、JDK1.8をインストールしても回避できませんでした。

> $ java -version
>   java version "1.8.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

OSとphpstormのバージョンは以下の通りです。

OS: OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
PhpStorm: 8.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FinderからPHPStormのパッケージ内容を表示して、

```
/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

こちらを下記のように編集してみてください。1.6*になっているかもしれません。
YosemiteにシステムインストールされているJDKを参照している可能性があります。

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8*</string>
```

Comment: 解決しました。ご指摘の通り、`Info.plist`内の`1.6*`を`1.8*`に変えたら、動くようになりました。ありがとうございます。